# Where to put the "position: relative;"?

Tags: html, css

I found out, that for my dropdown menu to show, I have to add position: relative to my css. But no matter where I add it, it gets displayed like this (with the navbar increasing its width. See the picture:

[image]

Code:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url('img/tape-measure.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 2000px;
  color: #000305;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Coming Soon', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', cursive;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #CF5C3F;
}

.mainHeader {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainHeader nav {
  background-color: #9cb34f;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 0;
}

nav:first-of-type ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

nav:first-of-type li {
  flex: 1 0 15em;
  padding: 0.125em;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

.mainHeader nav a:link,
.mainHeader nav a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.mainHeader nav a:hover,
.mainHeader nav a.Home:link,
.mainHeader nav a.Home:visited {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li a {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 0%;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 140%;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity linear 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #CF5C3F;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover {
  background: #3e3436;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Couture Anni</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ionicons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming+Soon" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="mainHeader">
    <img class="Logo" src="resources/img/Content%5Cvariation_800_e.png" alt="Logo">
    <img class="Margrit" src="resources/img/IMG_5347_small.jpg" alt="Annamaria Hofstetter">

    <div class="menu-wrap">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Movies <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">T.V. Shows</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Site Help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>


    <p class="Schneiderei"><strong>Schneiderei<br>&amp; Handwerk</strong></p>

    <p class="Willkommen"><strong>Willkommen auf meiner Homepage.<br>Schön, dass Sie mich gefunden haben!</strong></p>

    <p class="inBearbeitung"><strong>Diese Seite ist unter Bearbeitung.<br>Bis demnächst!</strong></p>

  </header>

  <footer class="mainFooter">

    <p>Copyright © <a href="#" title="couture-anni">couture-anni.ch</a></p>

  </footer>

</body>


</html>
```

I just don't get how I prevent the navbar from increasing its width, when the dropdown is shown.

Comment: In your example, it doesn't increase its width. Did you mean height?

Comment: Also, are you sure you need `position: relative;`? It seems like `position: absolute;` makes more sense from what you posted here.

Comment: Thanks to all for all the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
.mainHeader nav ul li {
    position: relative;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  //more code...
}

.sub-menu {
  top: 1.7em;
  left: -1.8em;
  //more code...
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url('img/tape-measure.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 2000px;
  color: #000305;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Coming Soon', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', cursive;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #CF5C3F;
}

.mainHeader {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainHeader nav {
  background-color: #9cb34f;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 0;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li {
 position: relative;
}

nav:first-of-type ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

nav:first-of-type li {
  flex: 1 0 15em;
  padding: 0.125em;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

.mainHeader nav a:link,
.mainHeader nav a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.mainHeader nav a:hover,
.mainHeader nav a.Home:link,
.mainHeader nav a.Home:visited {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li a {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 0%;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 140%;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top:1.7em;
  left: -1.8em;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity linear 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #CF5C3F;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover {
  background: #3e3436;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Couture Anni</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/1.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming+Soon" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="mainHeader">
    <img class="Logo" src="resources/img/Content%5Cvariation_800_e.png" alt="Logo">
    <img class="Margrit" src="resources/img/IMG_5347_small.jpg" alt="Annamaria Hofstetter">

    <div class="menu-wrap">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Movies <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">T.V. Shows</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Site Help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>


    <p class="Schneiderei"><strong>Schneiderei<br>&amp; Handwerk</strong></p>

    <p class="Willkommen"><strong>Willkommen auf meiner Homepage.<br>Schön, dass Sie mich gefunden haben!</strong></p>

    <p class="inBearbeitung"><strong>Diese Seite ist unter Bearbeitung.<br>Bis demnächst!</strong></p>

  </header>

  <footer class="mainFooter">

    <p>Copyright © <a href="#" title="couture-anni">couture-anni.ch</a></p>

  </footer>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The need for `position: relative` in the first place arises from wanting to use `position: absolute` on the drop-down menu's content. Absolutely positioned elements define their position based on the closest `position: relative` parent. Therefore the sub menu's parent is the correct place to define `position: relative`.

Add these to your CSS:

```
.dropdown-trigger {      /* New class */
  position: relative;
}
.sub-menu {              /* Existing class */
  position: absolute;
}
```

Finally add the `.dropdown-trigger` class to your second `nav ul li` element (containing the sub-menu). A few margin tweaks and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. You have to put position relative to `nav li` class and don't give `position:relative` to class `.menu li:hover .sub-menu`.

```css
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url('img/tape-measure.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 2000px;
  color: #000305;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Coming Soon', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', cursive;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #CF5C3F;
}
.mainHeader {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;    
}
.mainHeader nav {
  background-color: #9cb34f;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 0;
}
nav:first-of-type ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
nav:first-of-type li {
  flex: 1 0 15em;
  padding: 0.125em;
  position:relative;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  transition:all linear 0.15s;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
  color: #fff;  
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover,
.mainHeader nav a.Home:link,
.mainHeader nav a.Home:visited {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a {
  border-radius: 5px; 
}  
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {   
  z-index:1;
  opacity:1;
}
.menu .arrow {
  font-size:11px;
  line-height:0%;
}
.sub-menu {
  width:110%;
  padding:1em;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0px;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
  box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background:#CF5C3F;
}

.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover {
    background:#3e3436;
}
.mainHeader nav ul.sub-menu{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Couture Anni</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ionicons.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming+Soon" rel="stylesheet">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
   <body>
      <header class="mainHeader">
         <img class="Logo" src="resources/img/Content%5Cvariation_800_e.png" alt="Logo">
         <img class="Margrit" src="resources/img/IMG_5347_small.jpg" alt="Annamaria Hofstetter">
         <div class="menu-wrap">
            <nav class="menu">
               <ul class="clearfix">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="#">Movies <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                     <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">T.V. Shows</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Site Help</a></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
         </div>
         <p class="Schneiderei"><strong>Schneiderei<br>&amp; Handwerk</strong></p>
         <p class="Willkommen"><strong>Willkommen auf meiner Homepage.<br>Schön, dass Sie mich gefunden haben!</strong></p>
         <p class="inBearbeitung"><strong>Diese Seite ist unter Bearbeitung.<br>Bis demnächst!</strong></p>
      </header>
      <footer class="mainFooter">
         <p>Copyright © <a href="#" title="couture-anni">couture-anni.ch</a></p>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: a *"Please check this."* is not only odd (since clearly one *will* eventually check your example), but highly discouraged without pointing out and explaining the changes you did.

Comment: sorry for that I am not explain my ans but i am careful about it.